# Angular 5 page - make size tiny?

Tags: angular, optimization

Let's say i have an angular page with only 3 elements.

1. H1 headline
2. an image (~500kb)
3. a button

Is there any way to keep the page size small where the majority of it is the image loaded and only when the button is clicked only then it loads the bloaded angular app with all the javascript etc.

I just want to have simple pages while keeping the size small so people don't have to download the whole app files just to see an image.

The goal is to keep the page size under 1 mb.

Is there anyway to do that with Angular or should I just not use angular for my project? Thanks.

Comment: With proper lazy loading you can avoid the rest of your application fairly easily. No idea if that would get you under 1MB though. Perhaps this page should just be statically served and separate from your angular app?

Comment: Angular is framewrok so when doing one page app it is good.
If you need just some parts of js logic, maybe some components,
take a look at react or vue.

Comment: My recommendation would be to use Angular Universal to serve the pre-rendered app component as quickly as possible, then lazy load what you can. I was able to shave off a considerable amount of load time for one, but the paint times are also dramatically decreased.